# Real Numbers as limits of a specific sequence

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have come across this lemma in a paper
[image]

For your reference remark (b) states that: $a>b \implies a>\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b>b$

Axiom 2 states that: $\forall a,b,c\in S :$ the sets $\{\alpha | \alpha a + (1-\alpha)b \succsim c\}$ and $\{\alpha | c \succsim \alpha a + (1-\alpha)b\}$ are closed

What I can't seem to grasp is the jump from $\sum_i \alpha_i/2^i$ to real numbers. I figure that limits of such a series can perhaps take me to all rational numbers, but how it stretches into all reals seems a mystery.

Any and all insight will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: What I want to understand is that whether this series $\sum_i \alpha_i/2^i$ for $\alpha_i \in \{0,1\}$ will give me all rational numbers between $[0,1]$. If that is the case then the rest of this lemma seems straightforward to me.

Comment: Any real number can be obtained by a limit of sequence of rational numbers. In the lemma also it says $\mu = \lim \rho_i$.

Comment: "*whether this series ... will give me all rational number*" Yes, it will. That's just writing the representation of an arbitrary number $\in [0,1]$ in base $2$.

Comment: @dxiv can you link me to a proof/explanation for this? Thank you in advance

Comment: @VivaanGupta You could start with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number)'s page. Compare to the decimal representation of any real in $\,[0,1]\,$ as $\sum_i \alpha_i / 10^i$ where $\alpha_i\in \{0, 1,\dots , 9\}$.